# How to efficiently re-organise dict in Python?

Tags: python, performance, dictionary, coding-efficiency

The objective is to re-organize the two level `dict` in a single level.

Say the two level `dict` is given as below:

```
first_level_one = dict(my='my', ex='ex', second_level=dict(sec_one='sec_one', sec_two='omy'))
first_level_two = dict(my='my', ex='ex', second_level=dict(sec_one='sec_one', sec_two='omy'))
combine = [first_level_one, first_level_two]
```

The expected output should be:

```
combine_trim=[dict(my='my', ex='ex', sec_one='sec_one', sec_two='omy'),\
                dict(my='my', ex='ex', sec_one='sec_one', sec_two='omy')]
```

Based on the above requirement, the following code was drafted

```
first_level_one = dict(my='my', ex='ex', second_level=dict(sec_one='sec_one', sec_two='omy'))
first_level_two = dict(my='my', ex='ex', second_level=dict(sec_one='sec_one', sec_two='omy'))
combine = [first_level_one, first_level_two]
combine_trim=[]
for my_dic in combine:
    xx=my_dic['second_level']
    my_dic['sec_one']=xx['sec_one']
    my_dic['sec_two'] = xx['sec_two']
    del my_dic['second_level']
    combine_trim.append(my_dic)
```

There are two question;

1. Is the more efficient way compare to the above proposed code. This is because, there are many keys in the secondary level, for the actual case.
2. Is it possible to have only the `combine` variable compare to introducing the `combine_trim` which is used primary for `append` procedure?

Comment: This code will update the original dictionaries. Is it a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this, use `isinstance` to check if value is `dict` & using `update` add to tmp dict created.

```
combine_trim=[]
for my_dic in [first_level_one, first_level_two]:
    tmp = {}
    for k, v in my_dic.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
           tmp.update(v)
        else:
            tmp[k] = v

    combine_trim.append(tmp)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, appreciate it